# Keep in a same data structure methods of different types (type mix generic and normal) c#

Tags: c#, generics, types, delegates

I want to keep methods in a queue (need after to execute them in order) with their respective arguments to after invoke them with [DynamicInvoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.delegate.dynamicinvoke?view=netcore-3.1).

So, I got:

```
public Queue<Tuple<Action<string, bool>, object[]>> _myQueue;
```

I would like that the Action could receive bools and floats, that the I could have there a generic argument.

```
public Queue<Tuple<Action<string, T>, object[]>> _myQueue;
```

So that T can either be bool or float, and handle that internally in the method.
But tried quite a few things and does not seem to be possible. Is it?

Comment: If `bool` or `float` are going to require diferent execution paths then don't use generics; that is not how they are supposed to be used; generic means *generic*, not type specific.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. So to have a queue of methods that receive different argument type in the one same queue to be invoked afterwards is not possible¿?

Comment: No, unless you incurr in the penalty of generalizing to `object` some of the argument types. If reference types are involved there is some type variance allowed, under some strict type safety rules, that you could leverage if there is some commonality in between the different types you want to consider. But in your case, you are talking about value types and C# allows no type variance in said types.

Comment: I understand that when methods are overloaded the execution path is determined by the type received. I do not quite understand the same when a reference to an Action, or delegate that returns void (which is the same) is kept, as the execution path will determined by the invocation itself, not the type received. I still beleive there must be some way to make this happen

Comment: I now understand  the penalty of generalizing to object some of the argument types. I will try that out

Comment: I achieved what I wanted setting the bool to object type. I was not aware of the flexibility of this type for type specific problems like mine. Your comments were very helpful. Thanks a lot.